# NSolve function in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, numerical-methods

I want to use the NSolve function to solve system of equations. So I wrote the line:

NSolve[{0.1 == Exp[-((0.01 - y)^2/(2 x^2))]/(Sqrt[2 [Pi]] x), 
  0.3 == Exp[-((0.04 - y)^2/(2 x^2))]/(Sqrt[2 [Pi]] x)}, {x, y}]

After evaluating it, Mathematica is giving me the same form, without any results for x and y. Have you got any idea what's wrong. I think that there's something with my syntax.

Comment: Try FindRoot instead of NSolve. FindRoot is really aggressive and can often get an answer when Solve and NSolve can't. Check the documentation to see how to use that.

Answer (score 0):

@Bill is correct that `FindRoot` often is successful when `NSolve` is not, and this is one of those cases.  However, first you must replace`[Pi]` by `Pi`.  With this changes, a solution is `{x->0.0717056,y->0.213291}`.  To be sure that there are not more roots, consider plotting `y` as a function of `x` for both equations and see where the curves intersect.

In all this, I presume that you are seeking real roots only.  If you are interested in complex roots as well, use FindRoot with complex initial guesses.

Comment: I don't believe he had entered [Pi], but instead the entering and editing process had eaten the backslash in front of the opening bracket of the Greek pi. This loss of backslash on entry, and more often on editing, seems to be too common in forum software.

Comment: It might be sanitization to block unix shell, regexp and similar escaping constructs.